# datetime.strptime() not returning correct timezone info, only recognizes UTC as a proper time zone name

Tags: python, datetime

When I run:

```
datetime.strptime('UTC', '%Z')
```

It compiles just fine, because as specified [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) the representation for time zone abbreviations is '%Z'

But if I run...

```
datetime.strptime('EST', '%Z')
```

I get a ValueError, 'EST' does not match the format '%Z', even though like before 'EST' is even provided as an example for %Z at the [same link I provided above](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Python 3.5 or an earlier version? `strptime` has changed once or twice, it started out nearly useless for dealing with timezones and I don't think it's improved much.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
print(loc_dt.strftime('%Z'))
```

For refrence Please have a look at this link
(http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with timezones use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

```
from pytz import timezone
str(datetime.datetime.now(timezone('EST')))
```